# Why my begonia flowers are drying out

Tags: flowers, begonia

I have bought a begonia plant full of flowers. After 2 weeks, the flowers started drying. For adult flowers it is okay. But the young flowers are also drying. Leaves edges are also drying. What is the reason behind it? Can anyone help me? [image]

Comment: Is the plant in a container/pot and what size container? Does it get sun most of the day? How much and how often are you watering?

Comment: It’s in a 4 in container. It gets approximately 2pm - 5 pm sun. I water in every 2 days, after checking the soil moisture.

Comment: Do you mean a 4 inch pot? Is it the same pot you bought it in?